# How can I fix Window Placement via CCSM for Firefox?

Tags: compiz, firefox, workspaces

*(Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric with Unity 3D)*

In CompizConfig Settings Manager (CCSM) I activated the plugin *Place Windows* (? in German: *Fenster platzieren*) and configured it as follows:

[image: fixed viewports]

This works perfectly for Thunderbird, but Firefox always opens the first window on the actually focused viewport and not where it should. **A new window when Firefox is already running opens at the configured workspace**, even if Firefox runs on another viewport.

The described Problem appears when I open Firefox out of the Dash or from the Launcher or listing it in Startup Applications (Command: */usr/bin/firefox*). When I open it **by clicking a link in Thunderbird everything runs as it should**.

Furthermore: I started Firefox from the Launcher and switched to Expo mode (by pressing Workspace Switcher in Launcher). Then I saw appearing **Firefox on the configured workspace for a split second** before finally be opened on the focused viewport.

When I **restart Firefox after a crash or when it didn't close correctly before** (it starts then with what you see in *about:sessionrestore*) it opens on the configured viewport.

[image: about:sessionrestore]

I found out that it works correctly when I set `Preferences` → `General` → `Startup` to `Show my home page` or `Show a blank page`. Firefox opens on the focused viewport and not where it should **when this is set to `Show my windows and tabs from last time`**.

[image: startup settings]

Comment: with "class=Firefox" it works for me i.e. launching from the launcher or Dash firefox opens in whatever viewport you have configured. Do you need "& name=Navigator" ?

Comment: Good that it works for you - here it makes no difference whether I add "& name=Navigator" or not. Thanks anyway.

Comment: which version of ubuntu are you using - is this Unity 3D?

Comment: 11.10 and yes, it is.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this?